# Android: Why is it not recommended to manipulate views from a thread other than the UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm new in Android and multithreading programming and I read in the Android.developers docs that:

> It is not recommended to manipulate a view from an other thread than
>   the UIThread.

Ok I accepted the rule but now I would like understand why? Anyone have a simple example for me to understand why?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: to avoid race conditions

Comment: Because the UIThread is incharge in the drawing and it follows some schedule on what to draw in screens at every 12 - 16 ms so having business with other thread might ruin its schedule. Also if the UI is destroyed and you call some views in the other thread, it might lead to nullpointer exception since the UI is already destroyed. *yo late men. ;)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, to avoid race conditions is part of it. Its also just a bit of bad practice. UI Thread should handle UI issues, that's what its there for. Other threads should handle other issues, that's what they're there for.

Consider the situation of having a class that modifies a TextView based on some remote query. For this you should use something like `AsyncTask` which allows callbacks to the UI Thread.

Now if there is ever and instance where multiple threads are working on the same UI component, what may happen is that the "wrong" (unintended) one finishes first. This is a race condition.

Also, good programming encourages a separation of concerns. You don't have the manager working on the painting that the artist is working on, so why would we imitate this behavior in software?

Answer (score -1):

1. The upshot is: the UI should always be responsive. So if you have
   some operation that will take enough time that the user will notice,
   you might want to consider not running it in the UI thread. Some
   common examples are network IO and database accesses. It's something
   of a case-by-case basis though, so you have to make the call for
   yourself a bit
2. A thread should be used in a long running process that would block
   the  UI from updating. If it's more than a second or two you
       might want to put it into a background thread and notify the user
       with a dialog or spinner or something. If you lock the UI thread for
       more than 5 seconds the user will be prompted with a kill or wait
       option by the OS.

Comment: Sorry but you are not answering the OP's question. He/She is asking `Why it is no recommended to manipulate a view from an other thread than the UIThread`. Not the benefits of Thread.

Comment: My answer is also considers the above question as well updating the UI from the thread in brief so that people can understand, May be it is not helpful for you or you are looking something else. Please give a proper and better answer rather than comment on others.

Comment: Read what OP have said : `Ok I accepted the rule but now I would like understand why?` base on that sentence structure I can see that he/she is aware of the thread benefits but his question is opposing to the thread used and thats probably where the confusion is. BTW I already answered the question above.

Comment: somebody has a other simple example? an example of race condition ?